# How to seed data with CloudKit?

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

I need to create some records in CloudKit for each user when they start an app.

I can't just write a seed function that create records. Because when the user starts the app in two devices, they will each write their own seed record.

What I want instead is for the first device to write to CloudKit gets to create the record. And then second device will simply update the values of those records no recreate them.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options available to you, but all could potentially lead to race-conditions when attempting to write both at the same time, but the actuality of it happening is minimal.

No matter which approach is taken, you should always take the stance of *query first*. Check if the record exists, update it if needed, then write the new/updated values.

So, in your example:

- The first app would query for the record, and create the record - because no record exists.
- The second app to launch would query for the record, find it, then do nothing, because the record exists.

Each record in CloudKit maintains a `modificationDate`. So if you are really concerned about overwriting data that shouldn't be overridden, then you can add attentional queries and date checks to determine if the write should happen.

Comment: That's good advice, but here's the complication. The "seed" data needs to exist when the app launch for the data structure to work. Imagine a list of folders a user creates, but I have to show in the UI two "system" folders when the app launches. I cant wait for a query to the server for obvious reasons, because not enough time or no network. The user can also start putting files into these system folders immediately, so when it eventually syncs they have to go into the same cloud folders that other devices have "created". Not sure how to tackle this

Comment: Another option for this is to hard-code your identifiers for your seed data. This is how I handle seed data with a CoreData/CloudKit setup. This way, even if you try to import or store a record, you are guaranteeing that there is only a single source of truth. Only one record with that ID can be used locally, and only one record with that ID will be stored in CloudKit. Does this help your situation?

Comment: The thing with using a single ID to resolve conflicts is that CloudKit and CoreData use different IDs for their records/objects, and specially CoreData doesn't make these IDs easily manipulable right?

Comment: @Hamster The trick is to **not** use the Core Data `objectID` (`NSManagedObjectID`), for the identifier that is shared between CloudKit. Create a attribute on your core data models that contain an assigned UUID that can be used to identify both the Managed & Cloud objects.

Comment: The thing is that I wanted to be able to leverage CloudKit's and CoreData's existing code for merging changes between them. If I create my own UUID I'll have to manually handle the merging of CloudKit and CoreData elements, which I guess is something I won't be able to avoid.